# Change Sort after defining a variable

Tags: z3, z3py

Is it possible to change the domain of a variable after it has been defined and used in statements?. Example

```
s = Solver()
x = Real('x')
s.add(x < 1)
```

Now I want to change the domain of x to Int or Bool.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

But why do you want to do this? SMTLib is based on a many-sorted first-order logic, and variables can only have one sort. So, even if you can change the domain, it would be meaningless. (Essentially a type-error.)

Having said that, there's nothing stopping you from saying:

```
x = Int ('x')
```

at the end of that script. But the new `x` would be totally independent of the old `x`; i.e., a different name with a different sort and you'd lose access to the first one. Clearly, this is neither useful nor advisable. To wit:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver ()
x = Real ('x')
s.add (x < 1)

x = Bool ('x')
s.add (x)

print s.sexpr()
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

This prints:

```
(declare-fun x () Real)
(declare-fun x () Bool)
(assert (< x 1.0))
(assert x)

sat
[x = True, x = 0]
```

This is very confusing to read, till you realize those two `x`s are totally independent of each other. (And I'd say the `s.sexpr()` method is rather buggy since it doesn't print out valid smt2-lib, as what it prints would be rejected by a compliant SMT-solver, but that's a different issue.)

I suspect, perhaps, you're trying to ask for something else. If you describe what you are trying to do in detail, you might get a better answer!